# Why openCV library for processing doesn't work?

Tags: opencv, processing

i'm trying to use openCV library in Processing (on MAC)
I downloadded openCV lib for Processing, and paste it in Documents -> Processing -> libraries, but it doesn't work.
Below is screenshot. Strange things, other 3rd-party library that i downloaded is *.jar file, but openCV library consists of dylib file.
[image]

and this is most recent version of OpenCV lib for Processing : https://github.com/atduskgreg/opencv-processing

Comment: if you want opencv, avoid processing. (it's opencv bindings are all outdated, unmaintained, and bad)

Comment: @berak It depends. I agree, this [OpenCV Processing](http://ubaa.net/shared/processing/opencv/) wrapper is outdated, but Greg's Processing wrapper is actually not too bad at all (using OpenCV 2.4.5.0). The java bindings in general have less functionalities than the c++ library anyway, but Greg's wrapper along with the examples is really useful for people getting started with programming in Processing. If Processing is easier to use, Greg's wrapper works well, if c++ is easier to use, then use the library directly

Comment: ^^ ok, did not see the difference immediately, so probably you're right, and i was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Download [opencv_processing.zip](https://github.com/atduskgreg/opencv-processing/releases/download/latest/opencv_processing.zip) from [Releases](https://github.com/atduskgreg/opencv-processing/releases)

You should have an opencv_processing folder after you open the zip file which you'll move to the Documents/Processing/libraries folder. Restart Processing and have fun with the examples.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the screenshot, but I recommend you to download it again and placing the folder of the library inside the "Libraries" folder in Processing and restart Processing. Make sure you download the right version for your operating system.
You can make sure that the library works in Sketch-->Import library and see if OpenCV for Processing is available.
I find this library for processing really useful, it all depends on what you want to do. I also recommend you to use the GSvideo library and javacvpro library for more functions.

Good luck with OpenCV